# ¿Cómo se valida un archivo geojson para poder leerlo con python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, geojson

Estoy tratando de cargar [un archivo geojson](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iRbUeArOW9lsPS_6DHoEHxICxi0staHX/view?usp=sharing), pero aunque puedo leerlo cuando lo doy en su versión reducida después, la versión real me da el siguiente error:

```
>>> with open('research.geojson') as f:
...     dct = json.load(f)
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json\__init__.py", line 296, in load
    parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json\__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
```

Entonces como leer un archivo geojson con python?

Aqui esta la version reducida:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "geometry": {
        "type": "MultiPolygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              [
                -7.18458319,
                33.81124878
              ],
              [
                -7.18458319,
                33.81097412
              ],
              [
                -7.18319511,
                33.81097412
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "md898kw3185.1",
      "properties": {
        "name": "Ben Slimane",
        "type": "Province",
        "segments": {
          "UND": {
            "I don't know yet": 16,
            "No": 3,
            "Yes": 5,
            "total": 24,
            "intention_rate": 20.83
          },
          "ABS": {
            "I don't know yet": 1,
            "No": 10,
            "Yes": 1,
            "total": 12,
            "intention_rate": 8.33
          },
          "PJD": {
            "I don't know yet": 1,
            "Yes": 3,
            "total": 4,
            "intention_rate": 75
          },
          "PAM": {
            "I don't know yet": 1,
            "Yes": 1,
            "total": 2,
            "intention_rate": 50
          },
          "OTH": {
            "I don't know yet": 1,
            "No": 4,
            "Yes": 4,
            "total": 9,
            "intention_rate": 44.44
          },
          "RNI": {
            "Yes": 2,
            "total": 2,
            "intention_rate": 100
          },
          "IST": {
            "I don't know yet": 1,
            "Yes": 1,
            "total": 2,
            "intention_rate": 50
          }
        },
        "sample_size": 55
      }
    },
    {
      "geometry": {
        "type": "MultiPolygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              [
                -6.3649292,
                33.22292328
              ],
              [
                -6.38369083,
                33.21116257
              ],
              [
                -6.39487886,
                33.19342422
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "md898kw3185.2",
      "properties": {
        "name": "Khouribga",
        "type": "Province",
        "segments": {
          "UND": {
            "I don't know yet": 46,
            "No": 12,
            "Yes": 13,
            "total": 71,
            "intention_rate": 18.31
          },
          "ABS": {
            "I don't know yet": 4,
            "No": 79,
            "Yes": 1,
            "total": 84,
            "intention_rate": 1.19
          },
          "PJD": {
            "I don't know yet": 14,
            "No": 1,
            "Yes": 4,
            "total": 19,
            "intention_rate": 21.05
          },
          "PAM": {
            "I don't know yet": 12,
            "No": 1,
            "Yes": 7,
            "total": 20,
            "intention_rate": 35
          },
          "OTH": {
            "I don't know yet": 3,
            "No": 3,
            "Yes": 2,
            "total": 8,
            "intention_rate": 25
          },
          "RNI": {
            "I don't know yet": 3,
            "Yes": 3,
            "total": 6,
            "intention_rate": 50
          },
          "IST": {
            "I don't know yet": 5,
            "Yes": 1,
            "total": 6,
            "intention_rate": 16.67
          }
        },
        "sample_size": 214
      }
    },
    {
      "geometry": {
        "type": "MultiPolygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              [
                -3.77662611,
                34.86683655
              ],
              [
                -3.7705431,
                34.86468506
              ],
              [
                -3.75482011,
                34.86924362
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "md898kw3185.57",
      "properties": {
        "name": "Taza",
        "type": "Province",
        "segments": {
          "UND": {
            "I don't know yet": 16,
            "No": 28,
            "Yes": 14,
            "total": 58,
            "intention_rate": 24.14
          },
          "ABS": {
            "I don't know yet": 2,
            "No": 29,
            "Yes": 1,
            "total": 32,
            "intention_rate": 3.12
          },
          "PJD": {
            "I don't know yet": 9,
            "No": 4,
            "Yes": 23,
            "total": 36,
            "intention_rate": 63.89
          },
          "PAM": {
            "I don't know yet": 4,
            "No": 1,
            "Yes": 1,
            "total": 6,
            "intention_rate": 16.67
          },
          "OTH": {
            "I don't know yet": 3,
            "No": 3,
            "Yes": 5,
            "total": 11,
            "intention_rate": 45.45
          },
          "RNI": {
            "total": 0,
            "intention_rate": 0
          },
          "IST": {
            "I don't know yet": 2,
            "No": 2,
            "Yes": 5,
            "total": 9,
            "intention_rate": 55.56
          }
        },
        "sample_size": 152
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Por lo tento cuando intenté leerlo sobre [geojson.io](http://geojson.io/#map=6/31.889/-7.083) no tengo ninguna problema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que el archivo tiene BOM. El BOM es un valor opcional al comienzo de una secuencia de texto cuya  presencia puede significar cosas diferentes. Por ejemplo, en UTF-16 y UTF-32, la presencia de BOM señala el orden de bytes del stream.

En tu caso el archivo es UTF-8 pero tiene BOM (que se usa para indicar laa codificación nada más) y esto es lo que está causando el problema con `json.load`

La solución es especificar   `utf-8-sig` como codificación del archivo, ésta variante de UTF-8 en Python hace que el valor BOM sea lo primero que se agrega cuando se escribe en el archivo, mientras que cuando se lee y se decodifica, se omite el carácter BOM UTF-8 si existe:

```
import json 


with open('research.geojson', encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
    dct = json.load(f)
```

Comment: Gracias por todo el conocimiento que transmites, FJ, eres un gran maestro.